# Saving as Text in Spark 1.30 using Dataframes in Scala

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark version 1.3.0 and using dataframes with SparkSQL in Scala.  In version 1.2.0 there was a method called "saveAsText".  In version 1.3.0 using dataframes there is only a "save" method.  The default output is parquet.
**How can I specify the output should be TEXT using the save method ?**

```
// sc is an existing SparkContext.
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
// this is used to implicitly convert an RDD to a DataFrame.
import sqlContext.implicits._

// Define the schema using a case class.
// Note: Case classes in Scala 2.10 can support only up to 22 fields. To work around this limit,
// you can use custom classes that implement the Product interface.
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

// Create an RDD of Person objects and register it as a table.
val people = sc.textFile("examples/src/main/resources/people.txt").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
people.registerTempTable("people")

// SQL statements can be run by using the sql methods provided by sqlContext.
val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")

teenagers.save("/user/me/out")
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use this:

```
teenagers.rdd.saveAsTextFile("/user/me/out")
```

Comment: This will write one `Row` per line in the output file. You may need to use `map` to convert `Row` objects into csv before saving as text files.

Answer (score 9):

First off, you should consider if you really need to save the data frame as text.
Because `DataFrame` holds the data by columns (and not by rows as rdd), `.rdd` operation is costly, because the data need to be reprocessed for that.
parquet is a columnar format and is much more efficient to be used.

That being said, sometimes you really do need to save as a text file.

As far as I know `DataFrame` out of the box won't let you save as text file.
If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/ddl.scala#L194), you'll see that 4 formats are supported:

```
jdbc
json
parquet
orc
```

so your options are either using `df.rdd.saveAsTextFile` as suggested before,
or to use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv), that will allow you to do something like:

Spark 1.4+:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").load("cars.csv")
df.select("year", "model").write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("newcars.csv")
```

Spark 1.3:

```
val df = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> "cars.csv", "header" -> "true"))
df.select("year", "model").save("newcars.csv", "com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

with the added value of handling the annoying parts of quoting and escaping of the strings

Comment: Note that the Spark 1.3 method is deprecated and will be removed in Spark 2.0

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the migration guide https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-10-12-to-13, you can see that

> [...] DataFrames no longer inherit from RDD directly [...]

You can still use saveAsTextFile if you use ".rdd" method to get a RDD[Row].

Comment: TVM, but is there any option to save as text using the save method.  I have not been able to find much documentation.  The default is to save as parquet.

Answer (score 1):

In python: to get a CSV (no header) for dataframe df

```
df.rdd.map(lambda r: ";".join([str(c) for c in r])).saveAsTextFile(outfilepath)
```

There is also an extension developped by Databricks: spark-csv

Cf https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv